# Force installation of .Net Framework 3.5 under Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, installation

We have an application that runs under .Net 3.5, and customers (it's freely available on our website) can download it.

In the installer, we check if the registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" exists, and if it doesn't, we install "DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe /qb /norestart".

Under Windows 8, this installer prompts the user to know if he REALLY wants to install this feature that is needed by the software he's trying to run (you, know, just in case he wants to install software just to use some disk space) :

[image: .net 3.5 prompt]

Obviously, as any of you who has worked with end user knows, when they see a popup, many of them reflex-click on anything that looks like "no" or "cancel", so the software doesn't work and they complain.

Do you know of any way to force the installation of .Net 3.5 under Windows 8, without prompting the user for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe` in Windows 8. In Windows 8 run this command to [install .Net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx)

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs
```

*D:\ is here the DVD drive with the Windows 8 DVD/ mounted ISO.*

Comment: Thanks. So I need the customer to have their Windows DVD handy to install the framework ? :/

Comment: Yes but it's an end user. It's not an intranet or something, anyone in the whole world can download our software.

Comment: upgrade your project to .Net 4.0, this work fine in Win8(.1). For older system bundle the .net 4.0 Installer.

Comment: This is not a solution, as our software does not work (yet) under .Net 4. But we're working on it.

Comment: in this case you're out of luck. Your are not allowed to redistribute the files from the Win8 DVD.